# Netty allows same port to be bound multiple times by different programs

Tags: sockets, bind, netty

I'm a noob to Sockets Programming.Maybe am asking a fundamental question. Please bear with me. 
I wrote a sample netty server and started it from console. It runs fine. The problem i have is that when i run the same server from two console windows, i'd expect one of them to throw 'Address already in use' exception. It does not do that and I dont understand why. Please help.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChannelFactory cf = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100), new MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(1000,2048,25096,2,TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    //ChannelFactory cf = new OioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100), Executors.newCachedThreadPool());


    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(cf);
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {

        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            return Channels.pipeline(new ChannelHandler("test"));
        }
    });

    bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);      
    bootstrap.setOption("child.reuseAddress", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.connectTimeoutMillis", 30000);
    //NEVER bootstrap.setOption("child.readWriteFair", true);
    //bootstrap.setOption("disconnect", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("reuseAddress", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("connectTimeoutMillis", 30000);
    bootstrap.setOption("readWriteFair", true);
    bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9998));        
}
```

Comment: `bootstrap.setOption("reuseAddress", true);`: the reuseAddress allows binding to already bound address:port.

Comment: @Eugen, what you said is wrong - with `SO_REUSEADDR` he should be able to bind same port on a *specific address/interface* after wildcard is bound, but he should not be able to bind to wildcard twice. @user1623175, can you confirm with `netstat -na` that your app is actually listening on the port?

Comment: @Nikolai: so if process 1 does `bind(INADDR_ANY,portX)` then process 2 succeeds when it tries `bind(addressA,portX)` but it fails if it tries `bind(INADDR_ANY,portX)`? Is the behaviour OS/stack dependent?

Comment: This is standard behavior for TCP, see, e.g. Stevens UNP section 7.5. UDP, on the other hand, allows for completely duplicate bindings.

Comment: @Nikolai: tnx for pointing that out. I knew about the UDP/multicasting behaviour, I guess I need to brush up on the TCP side...

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov netstat -na shows both in LISTENING state! However, in reality only one of the 2 instances actually receives user inputs. The other just appears to be dormant. If i connect to the port using telnet, only one of the 2 started sessions consistently receives my inputs the other is...just dormant..  But, when i kill the console that Is receiving my inputs, the other one (that appeared dormant) starts to receive my inputs. I'd be happy if i could  get the 2nd console to throw 'Address already in use'.

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca  Thanks. Your tip did it. I changed it to false and now am getting the 'address already in use' exception. Thanks so much for opening my eyes to what was in front of me. Am an idiot. Serves me right to use a setting without thinking about it.

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca am not able to mark your response as an answer. Could you kindly post the same tip about 'ReuseAddress" an answer so that i can flag it as 'The Answer' and you can get due credit please?

Comment: Hmm, what weird platform/OS are you on?

Comment: @Nikolai: in UNP the section about SO_REUSEADDR lists the "should be able to bind same port on a specific address/interface after wildcard is bound, but he should not be able to bind to wildcard twice" behavior as a possibility, not the only one. It mentions that "completely duplicate bindings" is possible "if the transport protocol supports it".

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov am on Win7 using java se 7 and jboss netty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up the many comments above:

The `bootstrap.setOption("reuseAddress", true);` option will allow binding to an already bound `ip:port` combination. This is usually used to be able to restart a server if it crashed/got killed (so while the socket is still in the `TIME_WAIT` state).

In Windows it is possible to have two completely different programs bind the exact same `ip:port`. So even if in your app you have `bootstrap.setOption("reuseAddress", false);` it is still possible for another app (i.e. malicious) that enables `SO_REUSEADDR` to succesfully bind on your `ip:port`.

See here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: When several "ServerBootstrap" instances (with NioServerSocketChannel) bind/sync to the same port, what happens when a message is received on the port? Which channel is the message routed to?